# Error while editing and saving the data in PHP

Tags: php, edit

When I delete the values it works well. When I Search it works well.
Only when I try to save the data after edit I get an error.

I also tried to use

```
if(!isset($_GET['edit']))
{
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';  
    echo '<input type="text" name=criteria>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="search" name="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

But it did not work.

The error I receive is ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: criteria in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line 13.

The entire code is

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>  
<?php
    $page='search.php';
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("list") or die (mysql_error());

    if(empty($_POST) === false)
    {

        $data=$_POST['criteria'];
        if (empty($data) === true)
        {
            echo 'Please enter some text!!<br/>';
        } 
        else
        {
            $get=mysql_query("SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email, address, comments from names where fname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data) . "'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0) 
                {
                    echo 'There are no search results!!';
                }
                    else
                {
                    echo '<table border=0 cellspacing=25 cellpadding=1>';
                    echo'<tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone No</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Address</th><th>Comments!!</th><th>Modify</th><th>Delete!</th></tr>';      
                    while($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
                        {
                            echo '<tr><td>'.$get_row['SRNO'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['fname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['lname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['phone'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['email'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['address'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['comments'].'</td><td><a href="search.php?edit='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Edit</a></td><td><a href="search.php?delete='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Delete</a></td></tr>';

                        }
                    echo '</table>';
                }
        }
        /*
        if(mysql_num_rows($getf) == 0)
        {
            $getel=mysql_query('SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email, address, comments from names where lname='.$_GET['$data']));

        }*/
    }


        if(isset($_GET['delete']))
        {
            mysql_query('DELETE from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['delete']));
        }

        if(isset($_GET['edit']))
        {
            $getedit=mysql_query('SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email, address, comments from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['edit']));

            echo '<table border=0>';
            while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
                {
                    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                    echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="address" rows=4>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea name="comments" rows=4>'.$get_row['comments'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td><a href="search.php">Cancel</a></td></tr>';
                    echo '</form>';                                 
                }
            echo '</table>';

        }
        if(!isset($_GET['edit']))
        {
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';  
            echo '<input type="text" name=criteria>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="search" name="submit">';
            echo '</form>';
        }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two forms and just one

```
if(empty($_POST) === false)
```

how do I add a condition in if statement to filter each one?
Please help

Comment: Please stop echoing gratuitous amounts of HTML. It will make your life a lot easier to just jump in and out of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around the name on your input :

```
<input type="text" name="criteria">
```